# Invoking AX web service via C#

Tags: web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I am trying to connect to the AX web services. What I will do it to fetch the right price given a product and a customer.

I realised the right webservice to use is PriceListServiceClient and I am able to log in to it using windows authentication, but I cannot retrieve any data from it.

Here is my code:

```
PriceListServiceClient priceListServiceClient = new PriceListServiceClient();



priceListServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "yyy";

priceListServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "zzz!";

priceListServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "xxx";

CriteriaElement[] criteriaElement = new CriteriaElement[1];

criteriaElement[0] = new CriteriaElement();

criteriaElement[0].DataSourceName = "SalesPrice";

criteriaElement[0].FieldName = "ItemId";

criteriaElement[0].Operator = Operator.NotEqual;

criteriaElement[0].Value1 = "5637153175";

QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria();

queryCriteria.CriteriaElement = criteriaElement;

CallContext callContext = new CallContext();



var found = priceListServiceClient.find(callContext, queryCriteria);

Console.WriteLine(found.Currency);

priceListServiceClient.Close();
```

Any idea about why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/118741/246784.aspx

The Ax class for Price List document is AxPriceDiscTmpPrintout Class. This class wraps the TmpPriceDiscPrintout table, which is a TMP table. That's why you are not getting anything in return.

Answer (score 2):

Try filling in the properties in the CallContext (company and language).

```
new CallContext { Company = "zzz", Language = "nl"  };
```

Comment: I still get the same result